# How to Deploy ASP.NET Web App To Docker In Linux Server

Tags: asp.net, linux, docker

I am stuck from 3 days on deploying asp.net web application on Linux sever

Please help me for this solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This tutorial - [Deploy a Docker based ASP.NET Core app to Azure](https://www.yogihosting.com/docker-aspnet-core-azure/) will help you. Also refer [this youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDfax3lLKrg) on deployment to docker on linux server.